# dynamically include PHP based on browser features

Tags: php, javascript, html, xhtml, include

**REWRITE**

I have a website written in HTML5, and the same website written in XHTML. I would like to render one or the other based on whether or not someone is using a browser that supports some of the most basic features of HTML5.

**NOTE**

The site does not use the canvas, audio, or video features of HTML5. It is simply tagged with aside, section, nav, etc, and uses some of CSS3's fun features for styling embellishments. The difference between the HTML5 site and the XHTML site is minimal, and probably will be barely noticeable to anyone if I can make this work. The content is the same, it is just presented slightly differently.

**THE REASON I DID IT THIS WAY**

Once the dinosaur browsers are gone, I am hoping I can simply post the HTML5 site, and do away with the old XHTML.

I am running into some logistical snags and have not fully formulated how I want to go about this. I initially had the idea to use Javascript conditional statements to determine which PHP include to render. Yes, go ahead and laugh, I probably will some day too. While investigating that, a person commented that XML might make that possible. I am fairly capable with Javascript, PHP and XML. This is the first time I have tried to integrate Javascript with PHP, so now I understand why my original plan needed some more work.

Ultimately, I feel pretty strongly that this is how I want to move forward. I read about progressive enhancement versus graceful degradation, but I have decided that I want to give my client a beautiful website using all of the new semantic tags and simple style selectors to increase SEO and guarantee that when HTML4 goes away, this new site will stand the test of time...at least for a little while.

If you strongly object to this method, I am willing to listen to what you have to say. Please share your thoughts either way.

Comment: Given JS does not affect how PHP is loaded, I don't see how this is even possible.

Comment: You can insert <?php require 'lib/blah.php' ?> within JS.

Comment: And?  The php -always- loads before JS, and JS is client-side.

Comment: The php won't load until it is called within the conditional statement.

Comment: Javascript doesn't work like that, nor does PHP.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language; it renders the page before the user sees it, javascript is client-side, it only modifies what is already in front of the user.  PHP will _always_ render first, and since javascript is the result of that rendering, it cannot change how the php is affected.  An example of this is the very _fact_ you cannot see the PHP code of a web-page.

Comment: Well, technically you can have one page check if the user's browser is ancient or not in JS, and THEN redirect to whatever corresponding php page should load. But normally you shouldn't do this, it's messy and hard to maintain.

Comment: Why is it hard to maintain/messy?

Comment: I looked into this, and I am not crazy about the redirect idea because it would essentially cause me to send my users into two different locations. I agree that must be hard to maintain and messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask for is impossible; as I already explained, PHP is server-side, and JS is client-side; anything done php side is finished by the time the page is delivered to the user, so it is impossible for js to influence the php side unless your site, or content delivery, is done *completely* in ajax, which is a method of using js and php to retrieve information; in short, js sends a request to another php page on your server and returns the result.

That however is much more complicated, and I do not recommend it until you are more familiar with both JS and PHP.

That aside, however, there is a solution in php, although I do not have the complete code right now.

The solution is the php 4 and 5 function of [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php):

```
$arr = get_browser(null, true);
$var = "some browser";
if ($arr['parent'] == $var) {
   require('/php/file.php');
}
else {
   //etc
}
```

The above is before your answer update; I have nothing else to say in regards to said update.

**Update:** In regards one of the comments below in regards to ajax, I will attempt..  an example.  I won't attempt to call it 'simple', because ajax is anything but.. though back to the point...

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main_body">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
//some code to determine user-agent/browser, set variable 'agent' with result
var use_html5;
if (agent == browser) {
    use_html5 = 'yes'
}
else {
    use_html5 = 'no'
}

function retrv_body() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {//readState 4 is when the request has finished;
            //0: request not initialized 
            //1: server connection established
            //2: request received 
            //3: processing request 
            //4: request finished and response is ready
            document.getElementById('main_body').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            //set html of div with id 'main_body' to rendering retrieved from php_file_in_same_dir.php
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","php_file_in_same_dir.php",true); 
    //set type of form, boolean is in regards to whether the request is asynchronus or synchronous
    //most ajax requests are async, which means they themselves finish executing usually after the function itself has run.  I'm not truly knowledgeable regarding this specific thing since I've only ever used async requests, though I would assume being a sync request would mean the function actually waits until it returns a value before it finishes executing.
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //set the headers of the content.
    xmlhttp.send("html5=" + use_html5);
    //finally, send the data.  Depending on the data, the data may need to be url-encoded.
}

retrv_body();
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['html5'] == 'yes') {
    include('body5.php');
}
else {
    include('body_other.php');
}
//body generating code, render page.
?>
```

The above is just an example, and I would not recommend actually using it, save the `retrv_body()` function, and changing it into something you can really use.

Hopefully the comments I've put in the code will help in understanding; if anything is left to question, feel free to ask that I explain more thoroughly.

Comment: I did not directly respond to you because I felt you were being condescending. I understand perfectly what you were saying, I just wanted you to explain yourself. Now you admit that there is a way this idea is possible. If I wanted to check against every browser, I would use PHP user agent. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @nodirtyrockstar I did not mean to.  If you would rather I delete my comment above, I shall, and I shall attempt to re-write the above so it is not so.

Comment: You don't have to do me any favors. I am just looking for information.

Comment: Alright, so if you say it can be done with AJAX, would you care to explain further? I know my way around XML, and have used PHP's simplexml class in other areas of the site. I can write Javascript fairly well. This is my first time integrating them together.

Comment: @nodirtyrockstar he's trying to help, there's no reason to get offended.

Comment: Daedalus-thanks for the update. It gives me a lot to think about. In case you are interested in reading about asynchronous v synchronous AJAX, I found this old, but seemingly informative blog post about it: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/04/synchronous-v-asynchronous/

Comment: @nodirtyrockstar Thank you for that, it does explain some things I was unsure about.

Comment: It took some time, but I think I understand everything that is happening here. I will using JS to: sniff for old browsers, create a XHR, check ready state, open PHP file, get the data, encode it, then finally append it to a tag within the HTML. The PHP document will then print out whichever version of HTML it is told.

I am confused as to why you append the responseText to the innerHTML **before** opening the php file. Is this safe? What is the purpose of url encoding in this situation?

Comment: Hrm. Now that I think about it, I am wondering how this will allow me to render two different DTDs, if I am just appending to the div node, in this case. Is it possible to pull everything off the document and rewrite it with PHP?

Comment: Okay. I found that I can use the html5 DTD and old browsers won't cry. This is a great solution. Piece by piece, I am going to put this site together. It will be beautiful in 95% of browsers.

Answer (score 2):

No.No.No.No.No!

Two points:

1. Use [HTML5 shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) - Gives older IE browsers HTML5 capabilities)
2. [Progressive enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/) - You shouldn't code for different browsers. Your code should work in *all* browsers. Then add features that enhance, but are not required for the site to function, the user experience.